# Heterogeneous lists, large indices

Tags: inductive-type, universe

Recently I had cause to define a type of heterogeneous lists in Lean, and wrote

```
inductive HList.{u} : List (Type u) → Type u
  | nil  : HList []
  | cons : {τ : Type u} → {τs : List (Type u)} → τ → HList τs → HList (τ :: τs)
```

But this definition was rejected and Lean said it needed to live in `Type (u + 1)`, seemingly because of the presence of a `Type u : Type (u + 1)` field in the `cons` constructor. But we can define an equivalent type that lives in `Type u` by `List.foldr Prod PUnit τs`, so in some sense this universe restriction is fake.

I asked about this on the lean zulip and someone pointed out that Agda has a flag `--large-indices` that allows us to put this definition in universe `u`, although it's inconsistent with `--without-K`, and it seems like Coq has a similar option.

How does adding support for large index declarations like this change the theory (and why is the agda version sometimes inconsistent)? What use cases other than heterogenous lists are there for this sort of definition? What precisely separates the `HList` declaration or other potentially allowable thing with "large indices" from a type which genuinely lives in `Type (u + 1)`?

Comment: Can you link to that Zulip conversation?

Comment: This seems related: https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/310/why-does-agdas-without-k-option-also-affect-the-indices-of-inductive-types

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken but something like `inductive typeOfAllSubtypes: Type u | cons (t : Type u -> Prop)` would be a type in `Type u` which is *strictly larger* than `Type u`.  (By the injectivity of inductive definitions, there would be an element for every subtype of `Type u`, and by Cantor's theorem it is larger than `Type u`).  I don't know if it would be inconsistent, but it would be weird (right?) to have such a large type inside `Type u` (and I think it would break the usual set-theoretic model where each universe $\mathcal{U}_n$ is $V_\kappa$ for the $n$th inaccessible $\kappa$).

Comment: Here is a link to the Lean Zulip discussion: https://leanprover.zulipchat.com/#narrow/stream/270676-lean4/topic/Universe.20level.20of.20heterogeneous.20list/near/419661877